# Copying the table rows to another table deletes the rows from parent table

Tags: javascript, html

I will first explain what I am trying to do:

1. Copy the one table to another which i m creating dynamically.
2. Print the dynamically created table.

But, once i copy one table to another it deletes the rows from parent table.
Please see the following code which I have done:

```
 $('#anchorPrint').click(function () 
    {           
        //create a new table dynamically.           
        $("<table>", {id: "tblTransactionHistory_copy",'display':'none'}).appendTo("body");
        $('#tblTransactionHistory_copy').append("<tbody></tbody>");

        //copy the main table rows to dynamically created one.
        var rows = $('#tblTransactionHistory > tbody > tr');
        $("#tblTransactionHistory_copy > tbody").append(rows);


        var divToPrint=document.getElementById("tblTransactionHistory_copy");
        newWin= window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close(); 
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the task too complex, use [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead.

```
 $('#anchorPrint').click(function(){           
   var tblCopy = $("body").append($('#tblTransactionHistory').clone().attr("id","tblTransactionHistory_copy"));
   var divToPrint = tblCopy.get(0);
   var newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close(); 
   return false;
 });
```

The reason why your code not working is, If you pass any existing elements in your `document` either as `selector` or as an `element`, that will be moved out from its original position and will get appended to the target element.

Comment: Hello Sir, 
Above code does not made new table 'tblTransactionHistory_copy'. Because after above code 'document.getElementById('tblTransactionHistory_copy')' returns null.
I want new table to be existed because i want to make some changes in that before i print that.
In short i want to make a copy of a main table so that i can manipulate the things in it before printing it.
DO you have any solution on that ?

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: @user2746466 Just forgot to append the cloned element to the body. Can you check the code now?

Comment: I did that now, I can get the object of my newly created table. 
But now new problem is everytime when this code getting executed I am getting a new table created with same Id. I have written this code in a button click and every button click is creating the table. So i have multiple tables in the body now with same Id.
How do i stop that ?

Comment: Code not working in Internet Explorer 9..........can any one comment ?
' newWin.close()' closing the window in IE but not in Chrome. 
What could be the issue ?